# How can I compile each scss file into its own folder without merging them into one?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, webpack, sass

I have Angular components. Each component has a CSS file in its folder. I use SCSS preprocessor, so I need to make Webpack just compile SCSS files without merging them into one. For example

```
Before:
src
|-app
  |_component1
  | component1.html
  | component1.ts
  | component1.scss
  |
  |_component2
  | component2.html
  | component2.ts
  | component2.scss


After:
src
|-app
  |_component1
  | component1.html
  | component1.ts
  | component1.scss
  | component1.css
  |
  |_component2
  | component2.html
  | component2.ts
  | component2.scss
  |  component2.css
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can achieve this by following configuration in your webpack

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
{
...
  plugins: [
    ...
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].css"
    })
    ...
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
       ...
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
      }
      ...
    ]
  }
...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do it in a webpack and I don't even know if it's possible.
Install `node-sass` and then add it to package.js

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "blah blah blah",
  "sass": "node-sass ./src/app/ --output ./src/app/ --recursive false -w"
}
```

Read more how to use it [node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#usage-1)